# How to check if Account Trading is Allowed in MQL5?

Tags: mql4, mql5

What is the equivalent of MQL4's
`AccountInfoInteger(ACCOUNT_TRADE_ALLOWED)` in MQL5?

Also what about the equivalent of?
`TerminalInfoInteger(TERMINAL_TRADE_ALLOWED)`

they are not listed here: https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MQL5, the equivalent to `AccountInfoInteger(ACCOUNT_TRADE_ALLOWED)` is the same function [AccountInfoInteger](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/account/accountinfointeger).

It's also the same for `TerminalInfoInteger(TERMINAL_TRADE_ALLOWED)` - [TerminalInfoInteger](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/check/terminalinfointeger)

Comment: thanks I had been a bit confused because it wasn't on the "Migrating to MQL5" page

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of the official Documentation
and not only look at one single article from a user like us.

You can find it by useing "F1" on your written Code or behind the following links:

https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/environment_state/accountinformation

https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/runtime/tradepermission

This should answer your questions.
Nice day